# ASP.NET MVC and WCF Service Security - Authentication, Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, authorization, asp.net-mvc-routing, wcf-security

I am hosting a WCF Service within an ASP.NET MVC web application.  I would like the WCF Service to only be accessible to authenticated users.  Adding the configuration code below to the web.config file does not have the desired result:

```
<location path="Services/MyService.svc">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

How should I deny access to this service for unauthenticated users?

Comment: Testing in a non ASP.NET MVC project had the same result. This may not be caused by MVC as I previously assumed.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think Asp.Net's roles system will execute for a WCF request - I think you might have to use WCFs security (oh what fun)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding a Web.Config file containing the authorization rule within the "~/Services" directory itself instead of the Web.Config at the root of the website.

~/Services/Web.Config

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```